# Blazor layout component as mvc razor page layout

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, blazor

For login, registration pages I'm using MVC .cshtml views. I have a Blazor component as my layout for Blazor pages and I want to apply it for mvc pages as well and avoid duplicate my layout.
Is that possible? if not what's the solution?

I َAppreciate any help and solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-routable-components-in-an-mvc-app) for using razor components alongside MVC. Simply put, you don't use Blazor-style layouts. Rather, your MVC layout is utilized by the `_Host.cshtml`, and your routeable razor components are loaded within that.

Comment: I have a similar question. Adding a new Scaffolded Razor Page (CRUD) to my Blazor App whatever option I use, data table is visible but the page is completely unformatted.

Wondering how the layout for the Scaffolded Razor Page (CRUD) can be inherited from the Blazor App. Like for a new Razor Component.

Answer (score 1):

Chris guided us to the doc to refer to (Thank you, Chris!). For those who still wish to try using Blazor-style layouts in MVC or Razor page projects, follow all instructions in the doc Chris pointed out and you can get a view like:

[image: Blazor-style layout applied in MVC template]

The above is rendered with a Blazor layout component (`CustomLayout1.razor`):

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="container-fluid border border-primary p-3">
    <p>CustomLayout1</p>
    <div class="container-fluid border border-danger p-3">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

and a routable Blazor component which uses the custom layout (`LayoutTest_Body.razor`):

```
@page "/test"
@layout Views.Shared.CustomLayout1

<p>LayoutTest_Body</p>
```

As a sample for nested layouts, I added another Blazor layout component (`CustomLayout2.razor`) which is embedded into CustomLayout1:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@layout Views.Shared.CustomLayout1

<div class="container-fluid border border-warning p-3">
    <p>CustomLayout2</p>
    <div class="container-fluid border border-info p-3">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

and changed the `@layout` of `LayoutTest_Body.razor` from `CustomLayout1` to `CustomLayout2`:

```
@page "/test"
@layout Views.Shared.CustomLayout2

<p>LayoutTest_Body</p>
```

to get:

[image: Nested Blazor-style layout applied in MVC template]

Please note that:

1. Blazor layouts can only be applied to routable components (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) like `LayoutTest_Body.razor` at the first line of which holds `@page` directive followed by a unique route string.
2. Above samples are based on AspNetCore5.0.
3. Only MVC images are shown, but the same for Razor pages except for a few differences in configurations and settings described in the doc Chris pointed out. Be careful to follow all the instructions.
4. As is often the case, templates provided by Visual Studio do not necessarily follow the way the Microsoft docs show (e.g. doc: `app.MapBlazorHub();` , template: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); });`).
5. Passing parameters to layouts can be done through `App.razor`. In case of MVC project, (i) Create the parameter data and let `public IActionResult Blazor()` to pass it to `_Host.cshtml` via ViewBag, (ii) Let `_Host.cshtml` to pass the parameter data to `App.razor` by setting `param-[paramname]="@ViewBag.xxxx"`, (iii) Receive the parameter at `App.razor` which in turn passes it to descendants as `CascadingValue` and finally (iv) Let any descendants to consume it as `CascadingParameter`. Passing non-serializable parameter to Blazor components is not allowed at the time of this posting, but creating a dictionary for layout settings and passing it in JSON format could be one solution for a centralized management of various layouts.